# Crop image different format

Tags: c#, image, resize, clone, crop

I want to ask you for help in solving a problem.

I crop the picture with Clone. But there is one detail that affects the operation of the module.

In more details: I have a picture resolution of 1600x900. I need to get a thumb 400x300. Picture 1 is of type 16:9 and the Picture 2 4:3 ratio.

In my version of the solution of the second picture is cut from first. I need the first image smaller, and then cut off. So they look proportionate.

Comment: can you post what you have until now?

Comment: sorry I meant the code you have so far. that makes it a bit easier to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to resize your photo at 533x300 and then crop it to 400x300. This will preserve your image ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the great idea! I thought about it, but have not tried to implement it. I created a method that compresses the image by height, and then cut it to the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine what the deciding factor (height or width) is in your resizing, then resize and finally crop.

Something like this:

```
thumbHeight = 300;
thumbWidth = 400;
heightRatio = (thumbHeight / img1.Height);
widthRatio = (thumbWidth / img1.Width)

if (heightRatio < widthRatio)
{
 resizedHeight = img1.Height * heightRatio;
 resizedWidth = img1.Width * heightRatio;
} 
else
{
 resizedHeight = img1.Height * widthRatio;
 resizedWidth = img1.Width * widthRatio;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood the question. I thought you were asking how to get the resolution of the resized image.

Comment: Thank you tried to help! I solved this problem. With the idea of ​​which was written by the user Vio.